# Type Error.stackTraceLimit 'number' is not assignable to type '(limit: number) => void'

Tags: angular, typescript

In Typescript, specifically in a project with Angular 2 started from https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack, I get the following ts parsing error:

```
// Polyfill.ts (line 13)

Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity
```

> [ts]  Type 'number' is not assignable to type '(limit: number) =>
>   void'. const Error: ErrorConstructor

Doesn't make sense for me, since `Error.stackTraceLimit` does expects a number. I've tried with a function as typescript says as well, but then it crashes the browser.

Any ideas?

**Edit 1**

After merging with the latest master, it works.

**But**, I need to use Typescript 2.0.0 for whatever reason, then I get the error:

> error TS2430: Interface 'NodeBuffer' incorrectly extends interface 'Uint8Array'.

To solve it, I run `typings install env~node -SG` as mentioned in https://github.com/typings/typings/issues/554, to update the node typings.

And then I'm back to the error `Error.stackTraceLimit 'number' is not assignable to type '(limit: number) => void'`

Seems like something missing on the typings. Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest updating your project. If you are using angular2-webpack as a base for your project, it might be worth merging with master.

When I look at the code in the github project you have linked, line 13 does not match what you wrote.

`Error['stackTraceLimit'] = Infinity;`

Comment: That's a leftover from a play-around, but actually it is the same than using the dot notation. I'll try your suggestion of updating it.

Comment: Ok, I've tried what you mentioned. I guess it has something to do with the typescript version, see the edited question @DylanMeeus